# How do I properly save this JSONB into PostgreSQL using node-postgres (pg)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, node-postgres

So I have information coming in the GET URL, which needs to get passed into JSON and then saved (aggregated with increasing IDs to be correct) in the PostgreSQL DBMS. I wrote the following code, which seems to not save anything with no errors:

```
// Pg initialization
const { Client } = require('pg')
client = new Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'passwordhere',
    database: 'dbnamehere',
});

const createTableText = `
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pgcrypto";
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cases (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  data JSONB
);
`

app.get('/test', async function (req, res) {
  data = req.query.data;
  console.log(data);
  res.status(200).send(data);
// create our temp table
await client.query(createTableText)
//const newUser = { email: 'test@test.com' }
// create a new case
await client.query('INSERT INTO cases(data) VALUES($1)', [data])
const { rows } = await client.query('SELECT * FROM cases')
console.log(rows)
  res.end();
});
```

My package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.9",
    "pg": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
```

**UPDATE**

I have this error handling code at the end of the file:

```
 // Prints out more detailed errors
  if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    process.once('uncaughtException', function(err) {
      console.error('FATAL: Uncaught exception.');
      console.error(err.stack||err);
      setTimeout(function(){
        process.exit(1);
      }, 100);
    });
  }
```

I also tried installing `npm install express-promise-router` and adding the following code but no errors were printed:

```
var router = require('express-promise-router')();
router.use('/test', function (req, res) {
    return Promise.reject();
})
```

**UPDATE2**
This code without closing it prints out the JSONB, not how do I save it?:

```
const connectionString=urlhere;
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: connectionString,
  })

  const client = new Client({
    connectionString: connectionString,
  })
  client.connect()
```

**UPDATE3:**

I removed the asynchronous code and made it synchronous. I get the following error messages now:

```
(node:10860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Connection terminated
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/path/here/node_mo
dules/pg/lib/client.js:275:34)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/path/here/node_module
s/pg/lib/connection.js:73:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:659:12)
(node:10860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
 error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
 block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejectio
n id: 1)
(node:10860) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depr
ecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate th
e Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:10860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Connection terminated
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/path/here/client.js:275:34)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/path/here/node_module
s/pg/lib/connection.js:73:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:659:12)
(node:10860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
 error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
 block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejectio
n id: 2)
(node:10860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Connection terminated
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/path/here/node_mo
dules/pg/lib/client.js:275:34)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/path/here/node_module
s/pg/lib/connection.js:73:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:659:12)
(node:10860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
 error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
 block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejectio
n id: 3)
```

Comment: There should definitely be an error. Are you using a promise-supporting router like express-promise-router? You need that for promises to produce errors properly. (If this is the issue, there should also be an unhandled promise rejection warning on your console.)

Comment: @Ry- so i need to install it first with `npm install express-promise-router`? I added my package.json dependencies for clarity.

Comment: I installed it, still no errors :/

Comment: You can’t stop at installing it; you have to use it, too. Read the package’s documentation (README).

Comment: @Ry- it does not seem to help :/ I tried adding the code as mentioned in the updated question

Comment: If there are no error messages, did you try debugging to see how far it gets? Or at least sprinkle a few `try`/`catch` statements over your code?

Comment: @Bergi it does not insert the table or setup a table at all. How do I debug this?

Comment: @Bergi the catch does not catch anything at all...

Comment: If I query the Postgres DBMS I get the following output: `SELECT * from cases;
ERROR:  relation "cases" does not exist
`

Comment: I mean, use the nodejs debugger and step through the execution to at least check where it hangs. And yes, of course when you query the db afterwards the table won't exist, it was `TEMP`orary for the session only.

Comment: @Bergi how do I use the debugger without GUI? I only know how to do it with Chrome but that's not an option right now.

Comment: @Munchkin Why is that not an option? But anyway, how to use the debugger is a separate question. You should find all answers in https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#enabling-remote-debugging-scenarios and https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html though

Comment: @Bergi because the Postgres DBMS is running on the server only.

Comment: @Munchkin Re-read the part about remote-debugging then - or install a local development database.

Comment: @Bergi I installed the Postgres locally and while debugging the file structure is not shown for some reason... the script runs successfully since it prints out to the console..

Comment: You have to connect the client `client.connect()` before running any queries and end it `client.end()` when you are done. I do not see that anywhere... Even better: use connection pooling https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling

Comment: @madflow See the updated question

Comment: Updated the question again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a project generated with express-generator folder structure. But it follows the [node pg suggested](https://node-postgres.com/guides/project-structure) project structure.

```
.
├── _bin
|   ├── www
├── _db
|   ├── index.js
├── _server
|   ├── index.js
├── _sql
|   ├── create.sql
|   ├── insert.sql
|   └── drop.sql
├──.env
├── package.json
└── app.js
```

*db/index.js*

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool()
module.exports = {
  query: (text, params, callback) => {
    return pool.query(text, params, callback)
  },
}
```

In file above the credentials are loaded by .env file. But you can as in your question.

*server/index.js*

```
// notice here I'm requiring my database adapter file
// and not requiring node-postgres directly
const db = require('../db')
app.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [req.params.id], (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err)
    }
    res.send(res.rows[0])
  })
})
```

Now in sql folder you should put your DDL data.

*sql/create.sql*

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
  employee_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
  login VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(512)
);
```

here you can rollup the commands just using the `psql` or you can create a wrapper to run DDL with javascript and use it in your `package.json`

If you would like to do a wrapper in javascript

*sql/create.js*

```
const fs = require('fs'),
pg = require('../db/index'),
sql = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../sql/create.sql').toString();

pg.query(sql, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
})
```

Now in your package.json in the scripts section you can put a new line:

*package.json*

```
{
  ...
  "name": "myawesomeproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My wonderful description",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "createdb": "node ./sql/create.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

Now you can use `npm run createdb`.

So answering the real question here in your `/test` route should be:

```
app.get('/test', async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const { rows } = await client.query('SELECT * FROM cases')
    res.status(200).send(rows);
  } catch {
    res.status(500).send("Error. Detail: "+e)
  }    
});
//should insert data with post method, whole body is your current data.
app.post('/adddata', async (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    console.log(data);
    try {
        await client.query('INSERT INTO cases(data) VALUES($1)', [data])
        res.status(201).send('Data inserted');
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send("Error. Detail: "+e)
    }
})
```

Comment: That part with creation of a table before inserting comes from the official documentation..

Comment: gave you the bounty because you were the closest to an actual answer. Please edit your answer to contain it and I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your client is correctly connected to your Postgres DB, try to add a `client.connect()` and basic query with console log (outside your router).

https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting

Do your tables are correctly created meaning taht you are connected to DB ?

Is the NodeJS and the DB on your computer or in docker ?

And do the request give you any response code ?

Comment: Node.js and Postgres is running on metal. My tables were not created. I get no output at all

Comment: Ok then verify you are using the correct user/password or hostname, you can also try the postgres url. ( postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname] ).

Comment: So the code is just `await postgres.url(postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname]);`?

Comment: No, in your new Client, you can add `connectionString :` with your url correctly formed , it replace all user/hostname/port/user/passwd fields, both can work if infos are correct ones.

Comment: managed to get this printed out: `[
  {
    id: '8ff4d60a-82e7-45e0-a13a-3d9a438cf418',
    data: { case: 'it', section: 'ua' }
  }
]

` - this is my JSONB

Comment: For me the previous code in asynchronous should work, now the error talk, you don't handle promise rejection so manage your code to handle it. And connection actually don't work , did you try in any db administrator to connect to your databse ? pgAdmin / DBeaver etc

Comment: Yes, I've used pgAdmin 4

Comment: Can you create tables and insert values ? You may need to create roles with access.